# How make the lines bolder in the following image?

Tags: color, images, color-conversion

I am a web developer and not a graphic designer but I know basic Illustrator and Photoshop. My client wants this image to be a bit bolder:

[image]

The image is white with a transparent background (dark background added for preview purposes).

I tried saving as Illustrator file from Photoshop but it opens as a blank image.

Comment: Do you have the original file or the image in a vector format or just a PNG?

Comment: I added a background to your image to make it easier for people to see!

Answer (score 2):

by doing a quick search I found that the image you have is a vector available for purchase [here on ShutterStock](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?utm_campaign=freevector.com&id=259143320&tpl=39452-43068&utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_source=39452&irgwc=1).
This means that if they did, in fact, purchase it, they should have gotten the original vector file which you can (easily) edit. Ask them to send you the vector file and you'll be able to make the image bolder as they requested.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GD! Let us know if you have any questions